# Update XML string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm new to javascript and jQuery. I'm trying to get an XML string, update the value of one of the elements and get the new XML.

```
var header = "<RECORDS>" +
  "<USERDATA>" +
  "<USERID>ABC</USERID>" +
  "<UTEMPLATE>NEWLOAN</UTEMPLATE>" +
  "<FILEID></FILEID>" +
  "<ENTITY>DW</ENTITY>" +
  "</USERDATA>" +
  "</RECORDS>";

var fileID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

var xDoc = $.parseXML(header);
var $xml = $(xDoc);

var $elmFileID = $xml.find("FILEID");

$elmFileID.text(fileID);
```

This is what I have so for from examples I've seen but I don't know if it's right or what to do next.

What I want is a resulting string(either the existing header var or even a new var) with the content of the FILEID element as "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX". Eventually that string will come from a service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it this way:

```
var header = "<RECORDS>" +
  "<USERDATA>" +
  "<USERID>ABC</USERID>" +
  "<UTEMPLATE>NEWLOAN</UTEMPLATE>" +
  "<FILEID></FILEID>" +
  "<ENTITY>DW</ENTITY>" +
  "</USERDATA>" +
  "</RECORDS>";

var fileID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

/* Convert Text to XML Object */
var xDoc = $.parseXML(header);

/* Change the fields required */
$(xDoc).find('FILEID').text(fileID)

/* Back to Text */
var newHeader = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xDoc);

/* Show changed XML */
console.log(newHeader);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XMLSerializer, with a fallback to the .xml property if XMLSerializer is not available (e.g. in older versions of IE):

```js
function xmlToString(xmlData) { 
    if (window.XMLSerializer){
        return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlData);
    }

    return xmlData.xml;
}

var header = "<RECORDS>" +
  "<USERDATA>" +
  "<USERID>ABC</USERID>" +
  "<UTEMPLATE>NEWLOAN</UTEMPLATE>" +
  "<FILEID></FILEID>" +
  "<ENTITY>DW</ENTITY>" +
  "</USERDATA>" +
  "</RECORDS>";

var fileID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

var xDoc = $.parseXML(header);
var $xml = $(xDoc);

var $elmFileID = $xml.find("FILEID");

$elmFileID.text(fileID);
    

console.log(xmlToString(xDoc));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```